# Android Canvas inside of each row of listview without lag

Tags: android, listview, canvas

I realize this is a highly custom implementation, but im porting a app over from IOS to Android that has these photos in a listview that the user needs to be able to fluidly whipe off in one fluid motion. The only thing I could find on github anywhere close to this was this: https://github.com/winsontan520/Android-WScratchView/tree/branch_image_overlay

but,this uses a surfaceview and when implemented in my listview its EXTREMLY laggy. I did a bit more research looking for something along the lines of a photoshop eraser and came across some stuff using canvas to accomplish something similar with a single drawing area , but im not quite sure if what I want to do is possible in Android and if spending the next day or two learning canvas would be a worthwhile investment or if im barking up the wrong tree. Is this the way to go to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 1):

`SurfaceView` is actually a `Canvas` implementation that has some native improvements like duble buffering, vsync and such. But using it in a `ListView` is an overkill.

I say take your chance with a custom view. Just override the `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` and draw whatever you want. Learning canvas is pretty easy if you have some basic graphics knowledge.

As an another implementation idea, If you don't need all of your Views inside the `ListView` interacable when scrolling, you can use static images in `ListView` and when user touched one of them you replace static image with `SurfaceView` and go on. This way you only need one `SurfaceView`.

Also did you used the ViewHolder pattern  ( http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html ) when implementing the ListView? Might help with the performance but I'm not sure if it can be implementable in your case.

Comment: Even in a activity with only a single surface view as the header of a listview its very laggy which scares me a bit.

Comment: Than problem might be what you are doing in SurfaceView. Can you try SurfaceView alone without ListView and check the performance?.

Comment: I think im gonna just try to throw it into the top of a parallax listview lib so the scrolling aspect involved with listviews doesnt effect it , though id still like to and in the near future NEED to come up with a canvas/surfaceview solution that works in a listview fluidly with having a massive effect on performance and how fluid the list scrolls